# how to read json value for a key in jedis?

Tags: java, json, redis, jedis

I have a code where I need to get a json value for the key "product_id" using Jedis but I don't know if jedis.get() operation can output json directly. Here is the code below.

```
Jedis jedis = pool.getResource();
    jedis.select(1);
    String attributeName = jedis.get(facet);
    jedis.select(0);
    JSONObject productJson =  jedis.get(productID);
    String attributeValue = productJson.getString(attributeName);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the String JSON from Redis using `String redisCachedJSON = jedis.get(productId);`

You can then create your JSONObject from this String using

`JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(redisCachedJSON);`

Keep in mind that `get()` on Jedis expects the value stored on that key to be a String representation.

I am not quite sure what your object is but let's suppose the json is the following:

```
// Product json String
{
   "id" : 1,
   "price" : "2.63",
   "quantity" : 25,
   "attributeName" : "attributeValue",
}
```

You can map your JSON into a Java Class that's easier to handle than a HashMap (unless your json keys change dynamically) and map the json String to an object of that class using [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson)

```
public Class Product {
       int id;
       String price;
       int quantity;
       String attributeName;
}

String redisCachedJSON= jedis.get(productId);
Product product = new Gson().fromJson(redisCachedJSON, Product.class);
System.out.println(product.attributeName); // attributeValue
```

You can also do that using JsonObjectMapper

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
Product product = objectMapper.readValue(redisCachedJSON, Product.class);
```